# Does EXP4J handle decimals

Tags: android, parsing

I have this in my app;

```
Calculable result= new ExpressionBuilder(s1).build();
            size.setText(Double.toString(result.calculate()));
            size_num = result.calculate();
```

If I enter 100*.25 in S1, it gives me an exception. Without a decimal, it is fine. Is there a workaround where EXP4J can handle decimals?

Also if I enter a tab after my equation, EXP4J can't seem to handle that.  Does anyone know how to handle a tab in the equation before EXP4J is called?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Not those decimals.

By looking at [the source of the tokenizer](https://github.com/fasseg/exp4j/blob/master/src/main/java/de/congrace/exp4j/Tokenizer.java):

```
// ... snip ...

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

    // ... snip ...

    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {                                    // matches digit

        // ... snip ...

        while (chars.length > i + numberLen) {
            if (isDigitOrDecimalSeparator(chars[i + numberLen])) { // matches '.'

                // ... snip ...
```

You can see that the only time a decimal separator can be matched in a token, a digit is matched first.

So I suspect this will go just fine: `"100*0.25"`, but not `"100*.25"`.

> Also if I enter a tab after my equation, EXP4J can't seem to handle that. Does anyone know how to handle a tab in the equation before EXP4J is called?

The tokenizer ignores spaces, so either replacing tabs with spaces, or removing tabs all together before parsing should do the trick:

```
s1 = s1.replace("\t", "");
Calculable result= new ExpressionBuilder(s1).build();
```

Comment: Thank you, Bart.  I still have a huge learning curve in Java.